# Dynamically deny access to locations

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking to dynamically instruct ASP.NET to deny access to specific locations. So, instead of having something like the following in the Web.config, I'd like to do that through C# code.

> ```
> <location path="specialDir">
>     <system.webServer>
>         <security>
>             <authorization>
>                 <add accessType="Deny"
>                      roles="FileDeny" />
>             </authorization>
>         </security>
>     </system.webServer>
> </location>
> ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Page_Load( ... ) 
{
    if ( this.Context.User != null &&
         !this.Context.User.IsInRole( "FileDeny" )
        )
       Response.Redirect( FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl );
```

That would be a simplest solution at the page level. Anything more fancy, like a custom authorization module or a base page class is possible.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Made me feel a little bit stupid :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your requirements are, but you could have a base page class that parses the request uri and determines the access level by running directory/page information (with the user credentials) through whatever function you would use to determine their authorization to access that directory/page.

Answer (score 0):

I would go at this the other way around - add files to folders with the folder permissions pre-selected. You probably have your reasons for doing it this way, but...what if new permissions/roles are added later? Better to have a databased approach to this where you do a cross-check of user permission/roles against those assigned to the folders (and stored in a DB table).

A better way might be to use a single folder and assign access from a database field value.